# Name and size variables not working with i18next latest version

Tags: internationalization, i18next

I'm using `i18next` to handle my translations files; Just updated from version `1.7.1` to the latest `10.3.0`. Inside my `translations.js` I have some text for the image upload conditions, like this:

```
errors: {
  image_resolution: "Your image is %(imageWidth)spx * %(imageHeight)spx. Max allowed is (maxImageDimension)spx * %(maxImageDimension)spx'.
```

Also my `init`:

```
  i18next.init({
    resStore: Translations,
    resources: Translations,
    lng: window.data.locale.substring(0, 2),
    postProcess: 'sprintf',
    fallbackLng: 'en'
  });
```

But the output shows`%(imageWidth)spx * %(imageHeight)spx` instead of the actual dimensions, like it did using version `1.7.1`.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the sprintf-postProcessor? https://github.com/i18next/i18next-sprintf-postProcessor